# How to debug iOS slow app load time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I started building my app in iOS 8.4 and then 9.0.2 came out. Somewhere in that time, my app started to load really slowly when launched from the home screen (not from Xcode).

I ran the time profiler on my app and it takes 197ms to launch the main thread. But when I launch the app from the home screen, the app icon is depressed and greyed out for about 5 seconds before the splash screen is launched.

Is this an iOS9 thing?